# what is the difference in terms of effective use comparing stainless or normal steel wire brush/rotary tool?

Tags: steel, wire

When using a wirebrush (on a dremel head for example), which is more abbrasive and what are the advantages of stainless and normal steel?

Comment: What do you want to use the tool for?  What is the surface?  Do you want to use one on aluminum? Please add data to the question, if you could inform us of what you are trying to achieve, that really helps.

Comment: I am cleaning valves and valveseats, but I feel that is irrelevant to the question as the question is which is more abbrasive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stainless is typically softer due to chromium and other metals added to the alloy to give it the stainless quality. However, the difference is certainly negligible for a wire brush in this situation. The reason they sell them in stainless vs regular is that one will rust and the other will not.

Whenever I've gone to all the trouble of getting down to my valve seats I have chosen to clean them by hand with softer tools which will not risk damage to the seats. A simple pick and brush set, etc. Heavy on the elbow grease.

Comment: Argee with the elbow grease. I use dremel stones and a wirebrush to get the biggest lumps off the valves, the rest by hand.